# Hide applications from Apps menu

Tags: applications

I don't want to root my phone to delete some applications installed by the provider, but I would like to hide them from the menu, since I know that I won't use them often. I know that it is possible to do that with the alternative launcher, but I'm using the original one. Is there an application that can do that?

If it matters, I'm using a HTC Desire.

Answer (score 15):

The only ways I know to remove it are the two ways you listed (that you don't want to do):

1. Root phone.  Freeze application with Titanium Backup
2. Install a different launcher such as Launcher Pro which lets you hide apps.

Only a home launcher can disable what is show in the app drawer.  If your current launcher doesn't support it, then you are unfortunately out of luck.

Comment: +1 for the Launcher Pro option. It is the least risky (not everyone likes to attempt to root) and easily reversible.

Comment: Almost all laucher apps support hiding of apps..On my experience Apex lets you do it..

Answer (score 0):

I use ADW Launcher. I made a drawer with apps I use. Then I removed shortcut to main app menu, and placed instead a shortcut to my custom drawer.

This way I don't see apps I don't usually use, but I still have access to them in case I really want (I just edit my custom drawer).

And ADW Launcher isn't something that voids your warranty.

Answer (score 0):

The way I organize my Home Screen is that it contains everything I needed, and my App Menu contains everything else that I never needed to see. This way, I almost never need to use the App Menu, except when using a new application.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide your any of the apps from app launcher and can use them any time.
You can use Nova Launcher to hide apps from the main screen and later access them whenever required.

This article will clearly explain to you about how to do this with nova launcher : [How to hide apps in Android](https://www.experthoot.com/how-to-hide-apps-on-android/)

You can also use apex launcher and few other freely available apps on play store. But I would prefer the Nova Launcher. I'm personally using it to hide apps from my wife and I would recommend it to you. It's smooth and easy.