# How to Hide an Application

Tags: applications

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 Plus and I have one application listed in my Settings - Manage Apps list that I want hidden from the user.  This is not an icon - it is the application name in the list of apps on the phone under the setting section.  Is there a way to either 1. hide the app (make it not visible on the app list) or 2. lock the app list so the user cannot open it to see what apps are listed there.  I do not want to password protect the whole phone or individual icons, just the Manage Applications section under Settings.

Best solution is to figure out how to make that app name hidden from the Manage Applications list, but I am not sure that is possible without either deactivating or removing it.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Related: [Hide applications from Apps menu](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/5962)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to remove or deactivate the application, then either:

- you can install a 3rd party launcher (like Nova) and hide the application from the app drawer.
- you can download [Hide it pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartanuj.hideitpro&hl=en) and basically you can anything in your phone.

Answer (score 0):

On 4.3 you could create a *restricted user profile*, and block access to the Settings app from that profile (and to the app you want to hide, presumably). If you're not on 4.3, or you're not willing to create a restricted user profile, you're out of luck.

Hypothetically, you could replace the Settings app with one that's programmed to hide the app you're interested in, using a custom ROM (or if you're rooted, by just replacing that package), but I don't think someone has already patched the Settings app that way, so you would probably have to do a bit of programming to achieve it. Such a piece of software would be very like what's known in the PC world as a *rootkit*, a type of malware, so you should think very carefully before searching for or attempting such a thing.

Comment: Aren't user profiles--even restricted ones--still only limited to tablets?

Comment: Oh, of course: it hadn't occurred to me that the OP is particularly interested in a phone. Looks like he's in the "out of luck" case, then.